# Java process exits when accessed via the child class

Tags: java

I have a "class A" which holds a protected HashTable of some processes which have been started inside of class A. "Class B" extends "class A" and when I retrieve the process from within class B, it shows that the process has exited while if I access the same process from within class A, the process is still alive and I can retrieve its result. why is that?

```java
public abstract class A {

    protected final Map<String, Process> processCache = new Hashtable<>();

    public void processResults(String processId) {
        getScanProcessResult(processId);
        // other logic
    }

    protected abstract String getScanProcessResult(String id);
}

public class B extends A {

    @Override
    protected String getScanProcessResult(String processId) {
        Process process = super.processCache.get(processId);
        if (process.isAlive) {
            // it's not alive
        }
    }
}
```

Also the way this is implemented is as following :
there are 2 batch jobs.
the first one starts some processes and saves their objects in the processCache
the second job starts one minute after the initial one and retrieves the results from those process objects.
the same logic works fine if instead I use this :

```
public void processResults(String processId) {
    Process process = processCache.get(processId);
    if (process.isAlive) {
        // it's alive
    }
    // other logic
}
```

Comment: Without seeing the code we can only guess. But this sounds like a nightmare of race conditions. Are you sure you're not just observing the results of checking the same process at different moments in time? It might be that it has nothing to do with subclassing and everything to do with timing.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to provide a [mre] demonstrating the problem.

Comment: @SilvioMayolo I had implemented the same logic on another application and this kind of process that I run would never exit itself, no matter when I accessed it, It was always alive and I could retrieve its String result. Now I have implemented the same thing but with just that difference which I mentioned in the question. Right now I removed the difference and it works like a charm. besides, this is implemented as 2 jobs, first job starts a couple of processes and caches their objects and another job one minute after the initial one retrieves those process objects and extracts their result

Comment: @Slaw sample code added to the question

Comment: Perhaps you can find clues by looking at the output and error streams, and checking `exitValue()`.

Comment: Also, absence of all the code involved will make this harder for anyone to help. Even the posted code has this, which isn't valid: `public class B extends class A` ("extends class A" should be "extends A"). This needs an MRE.